# Transformar texto em links de breadcrumb

Tags: javascript, breadcrumbs

Eu tenho duas variáveis

```
var link_breadcrumb = "geral1_titulo1_parte1_conteudo1";
var texto_breadcrumb = "Geral 1 - Título 1 - Parte 1 - Conteúdo 1";
```

Gostaria de montar o breadcrumb com os links

```
var breadcrumb_montado = "<a href="#geral1">Geral 1</a> / <a href="#geral1_titulo1">Título 1</a> / <a href="#geral1_titulo1_parte1">Parte 1</a> / <a href="#geral1_titulo1_parte1_conteudo1">Conteúdo 1</a>";
```

Alguém sabe como fazer isso em javascritp?

Comment: Sua pergunta não está clara, poderia explica-lá melhor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá ficaria basicamente assim:

```
var link_breadcrumb = "geral1_titulo1_parte1_conteudo1";
var texto_breadcrumb = "Geral 1 - Título 1 - Parte 1 - Conteúdo 1";


var links = link_breadcrumb.split('_');
var textos = texto_breadcrumb.split(' - ')

var breadcrumb_montado = links.map(function (link, index) {
    return "<a href=" + link + ">" + textos[index] + "</a>";
}).join(" / ");
```

O `split` ele separa a string a partir de um delimitador, retornando um `array`.

Como os dois array vão ficar do mesmo tamanho basicamente vc precisa percorrer um depois com o map e consegue o texto do outro a partir do index.

E e join serve somente para concatenar o `array` gerado, transformando em `string`. Sendo que vc pode indicar o que vai ta entre cada elemento.